# How can I find the highest value between rows every time that they met a certain condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have been struggling with a problem with my data frame build in pandas that is current like this

```
MyDataFrame:

Index   Status    Value
0              A            10
1              A             8
2              A             5
3              B             9
4              B             5
5              A             1
6              B             2
7              A             3
8              A             5
9              A             1

The desired output would be:
Index   Status    Value
0              A            10
1              B             9
2              A             1
3              B             2
4              A             5
```

So far I tried to use range and while conditions to filter, however, if I put a conditional like :

```
for i in range:
        if Status[i] == "A":
          print(Value[i])
        if  Status == "B":
           break
```

** The code above is more an example of what I have been trying to reach my goal, I tried to use .iloc and range with while, but maybe in the wrong way idk.*

The desired output isn't printed.

One thing that complicates this filtering process is that MyDataFrame changes every time that I run the script since it uses another base of data to create this DataFrame.

I believe that I'm missing something simple, but it has been almost a week and I can't figure out.

Thanks in advance for all your answers and support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try using `shift` with `cumsum` create the `groupby` key , then it is `groupby` + `agg`

```
out = df.groupby(df.Status.ne(df.Status.shift()).cumsum()).agg({'Status':'first','Value':'max'})
Out[14]: 
       Status  Value
Status              
1           A     10
2           B      9
3           A      1
4           B      2
5           A      5
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this solution, worked like a charm. Just one more question, in case I want to reach the highest value of the A rows and the lowest value of the B rows, should I add another agg?

Tks again

Comment: @Ikaro change agg({'A':'max','B':'min'}) :-)

Comment: sorry if is a dumb question, but in this case, the final code, in this case, would be?:

out = df.groupby(df.Status.ne(df.Status.shift()).cumsum()).agg({'Status':'first','Value':'max', 'A':'max','B':'min})

Thank you again for all the answers and assitance.

Comment: Using this way its returning the error:^

raise SpecificationError(f"Column(s) {cols} do not exist")
pandas.core.base.SpecificationError: Column(s) ['A', 'B'] do not exist 

unfortunately =/

Answer (score 2):

Very close to @BEN_YO:

```
grp = (df['Status'] != df['Status'].shift()).cumsum()
df.loc[df.groupby(grp)['Value'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
      Status  Value
Index              
0          A     10
3          B      9
5          A      1
6          B      2
8          A      5
```

Create groups using shift and inequality with `cumsum`, then `groupby` and find the index of the max value of 'Value', `idxmax`, and filter the dataframe using `loc`

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was extremely helpfu.